# Iam unable to send mail from mutt it always gives an error

Tags: email, mail, mutt

So hi I followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MuttAndGmail).
But whenever I try to send mail it gives an error message like this ::

```
Output of the delivery process (all)

msmtp: authentication failed (method PLAIN)

msmtp: server message: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more

+at
msmtp: server message: 535 5.7.8
+https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c64sm28182897pfa.0 - gsmtp
msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /home/sharikzama/.msmtprc)


i:Exit  -:PrevPg  <Space>:NextPg ?:Help

Error sending message, child exited 77 (Insufficient permission.).
```

This is my .msmtprc file:

```
 account default              
 host smtp.gmail.com          
 port 587                     
 from "xx@xx.com"   
 tls on                       
 tls_starttls on              
 tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
 auth on                     
 user "sharikzama"       
 password "********"       
 logfile ~/.msmtp.log
```

This is my .muttrc file :

```
#======================================================#
# Boring details
set realname ="sharikzama"

set from = "xx@xx.com"

set use_from = yes

set envelope_from ="yes"

set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"

# If not set in environment variables:
set spoolfile = /var/spool/mail/sharikzama

#======================================================#
# Folders
set folder="~/Mail"                # Mailboxes in here

set record="+sent"                 # where to store sent messages

set postponed="+postponed"         # where to store draft messages

set move=no                          # Don't move mail from the spool.

#======================================================#
# Watch these mailboxes for new mail:
mailboxes ! +Fetchmail +slrn +mutt

set sort_browser=alpha    # Sort mailboxes by alpha(bet)

#======================================================#
# Order of headers and what to show

hdr_order Date: From: User-Agent: X-Mailer \

To: Cc: Reply-To: Subject:

ignore *

unignore Date: From: User-Agent: X-Mailer  \

To: Cc: Reply-To: Subject:

#======================================================#
# which editor do you want to use? 
# vim of course!

set editor="vim -c 'set tw=70 et' '+/^$' " 

set edit_headers          # See the headers when editing

#======================================================#
# Aliases

set sort_alias=alias     # sort aliases in alpha order by alias name

#======================================================#
# Odds and ends

set markers          # mark wrapped lines of text in the pager with a +

set smart_wrap       # Don't wrap mid-word

set pager_context=5  # Retain 5 lines of previous page when scrolling.

set status_on_top    # Status bar on top.

push <show-version>  # Shows mutt version at startup

macro index,pager I '<shell-escape> fetchmail -v<enter>'
```

Please help me guys..!!

Comment: It's just as it says in the error output. You're username and password aren't correct. Try re-entering your credentials and make sure they're correct.

Comment: Yes I did re-enter it and everything is fine in .msmtprc file but it always gives the same error message.

Comment: @shariksid That is my guide, continued here: http://www.andrews-corner.org/mutt.html :). Have you enable POP support for your account: http://gmail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13273 ?